# Value is deprecated (2)

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-error

Im new on this and i have this error in this code.

```
"acrylicOpacity": 0.4,
```

Value is deprecated (2) [Lin.34, col 13]

Anyone can explain me whats wrong and why?

Comment: First result from a search - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/terminal/issues/595

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right line? Column 13 is in the middle of the string literal. Sometimes this kind of tooling can count whitespace/blank lines in the wrong way, for example. So line 34 from the perspective of the tool throwing the error might not be line 34 in your editor window.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute was [removed from Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-appearance#transparency) in version 1.12+. You likely updated recently.

Try setting this new parameter:

```
"useAcrylic": true,
```

That defaults to 50% opacity. To get exactly what you had before, try this:

```
"useAcrylic": true,
"opacity": 40,
```